# Split array into 3 pieces and put it in separated divs

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I'm using Bootstrap tabs and I need help to make 1 array content split into 3 pieces like this:

Example array:

```php
$arr = array(
   0 => array(
      'title' => 'sometitle'
   ),
   1 => array(
      'title' => 'sometitle'
   ),
   2 => array(
      'title' => 'sometitle'
   ),
   3 => array(
      'title' => 'sometitle'
   ),
   4 => array(
      'title' => 'sometitle'
   ),
   5 => array(
      'title' => 'sometitle'
   ),
);
```

And I want it to make like this:

```html
<div>
    sometitle
    sometitle
</div>

<div>
    sometitle
    sometitle
</div>

<div>
    sometitle
    sometitle
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just target the main array, and use `array_chunk()` as

```
$arrayToSplit =  array("a", "b", "c");

$chunk = array_chunk($arrayToSplit, 3);
```

then simply call them using their numeric indexes

```
echo $chunk[0] // a
```